# HoPoMo in PHP: I don't know how to implement - "max{"

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am woefully undereducated in math - so I have to ask a question that I'm assuming is fairly basic.

[image]

This is a formula in the HoPoMo Honeybee Population Model for modeling the effects of season on a typical beehive. The results should look something like this where:

```
t = day of the year (1-365)
x1 = 385
x2 = 30
x3 = 36
x4 = 155
x5 = 30
```

[image]

I've attempted to implement this via php like this

```
function season($t){
 $x1 = 365;  //undefined in literature
 $x2 = 30;   //uil
 $x3 = 36;   //uil
 $x4 = 155;  //Day of maximum egg laying activity
 $x5 = 30;  //uil

    $o1 = 1 -(              1 / 
        (1+ $x1 * M_E^(-2*$t / $x2) ) );


    $o2 =                   1 / 
            (1 + $x3 * M_E^(-2*($t-$x4)/$x5 ) );

    //what I think when I see max{
    if ($o1 > $o2) return $o1;
 if ($o1 < $o2) return $o2;
return $o1;


}
```

I posted here because I assume that this is not a coding problem but rather a lack of understanding of what max{ means and how to implement it even on paper. Just imagine I'm a 3rd grader needing a rough approximation of this.

Comment: I don't speak PHP, but what happens if \$o1 = \$o2?  And, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Im pretty sure max{ isn't asking for the bigger of the two. What is it asking for and how do I stupidly, naively implement that on paper.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that something called "max" *is* asking for the bigger of those two expression values. (If not, then I shall forever avoid learning PHP! :-) Assuming your PHP implementations of those expressions are okay, the only issue I can see is that you'll fall off the end of your function if they turn out to be equal (assuming that's possible).

Comment: That's a shame, I'd rather my code not work because of something I don't know rather than because of a mistake in my coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP there is a function called `max` that returns the largest value of the parameters you give it. So if you write

```
return max($o1, $o2);
```

You will get the largest `$o1` and `$o2`, which is what you seek.

Answer (score 1):

Logically one should consider the case if \$o1 and \$o2 are equal. To clarify in this case the php max function returns the first entry so the above answer is correct.